# Difference in JsonPath inner object property

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

This is my data:

```
{
    "_embedded": {
        "analytics": {
            "originCode": "PRD"
        },
        "product": {
            "id": "wi412784",
            "description": "AH Wa­ter­fles met in­fu­ser blauw (500 ml)",
            "unitSize": "per stuk",
            "brandName": "AH",
            "categoryName": "Koken, tafelen, non-food/Bidon",
            "availability": {
                "orderable": true,
                "label": "Leverbaar"
            },
            "priceLabel": {
                "now": 3.49,
                "was": 4.99
            },
            "discount": {
                "type": {
                    "name": "BONUS"
                },
                "label": "30% korting"
            },
            "images": [{
                "title": "Waterfles met infuser blauw (500 ml)",
                "width": 80,
                "height": 80,
                "link": {
                    "href": "https://www.ah.nl.kpnis.nl/static/product/AHI_434d50323838313031_1_80x80_JPG.JPG"
                }
            }, {
                "title": "Waterfles met infuser blauw (500 ml)",
                "width": 200,
                "height": 200,
                "link": {
                    "href": "https://www.ah.nl.kpnis.nl/static/product/AHI_434d50323838313031_1_200x200_JPG.JPG"
                }
            }, {
                "title": "Waterfles met infuser blauw (500 ml)",
                "width": 708,
                "height": 708,
                "link": {
                    "href": "https://www.ah.nl.kpnis.nl/static/product/AHI_434d50323838313031_1_LowRes_JPG.JPG"
                }
            }, {
                "title": "Waterfles met infuser blauw (500 ml)",
                "width": 48,
                "height": 48,
                "link": {
                    "href": "https://www.ah.nl.kpnis.nl/static/product/AHI_434d50323838313031_1_48x48_GIF.GIF"
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Inside product I want to get the href String of the last image.

On the Jsonpath evaluator websites that I know: 
http://jsonpath.com/ and http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/ this
`$._embedded.[?(@.id)].images[2].link.href` is valid JSON and returns the href.

Trying this inside [Jayway JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) won't work and returns an emtpy List. To get it working I need to do have this query `$..[?(@.id)].images[2].link.href`

Why isn't the first query valid inside Jayway JsonPath?

Edit: 
This is my test method

```
@Test
    public void getImgSrc() {
        String jsonData = "{\"_embedded\": {\"analytics\": {\"originCode\": \"PRD\"},\"product\": {\"id\": \"wi412784\",\"description\": \"AH Wa\u00ADter\u00ADfles met in\u00ADfu\u00ADser blauw (500 ml)\",\"unitSize\": \"per stuk\",\"brandName\": \"AH\",\"categoryName\": \"Koken, tafelen, non-food/Bidon\",\"availability\": {\"orderable\": true,\"label\": \"Leverbaar\"},\"priceLabel\": {\"now\": 3.49,\"was\": 4.99},\"discount\": {\"type\": {\"name\": \"BONUS\"},\"label\": \"30% korting\"},\"images\": [    {\"title\": \"Waterfles met infuser blauw (500 ml)\",\"width\": 80,\"height\": 80,\"link\": {\"href\": \"https://www.ah.nl.kpnis.nl/static/product/AHI_434d50323838313031_1_80x80_JPG.JPG\"}},{\"title\": \"Waterfles met infuser blauw (500 ml)\",\"width\": 200,\"height\": 200,\"link\": {\"href\": \"https://www.ah.nl.kpnis.nl/static/product/AHI_434d50323838313031_1_200x200_JPG.JPG\"}},{\"title\": \"Waterfles met infuser blauw (500 ml)\",\"width\": 708,\"height\": 708,\"link\": {\"href\": \"https://www.ah.nl.kpnis.nl/static/product/AHI_434d50323838313031_1_LowRes_JPG.JPG\"}},{\"title\": \"Waterfles met infuser blauw (500 ml)\",\"width\": 48,\"height\": 48,\"link\": {\"href\": \"https://www.ah.nl.kpnis.nl/static/product/AHI_434d50323838313031_1_48x48_GIF.GIF\"}}]}}}";

        DocumentContext cxt = JsonPath.parse(jsonData);
        List<String> href = cxt.read("$._embedded.[?(@.id)].images[2].link.href");
        Assert.assertEquals("https://www.ah.nl.kpnis.nl/static/product/AHI_434d50323838313031_1_LowRes_JPG.JPG", href.get(0));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `product` in your path.

This will work -

```
List<String> href = cxt.read("$._embedded.product[?(@.id)].images[2].link.href");
```

Comment: Yes, there apparently are minor differences between Jayway JsonPath and Goessner JsonPath.